# How to know once a new application gets added into USC

Tags: software-center

Is there any way so that I can get to know once any new application gets added into Ubuntu Software Center? Do I have to join something for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new applications appear in the "What's New" section:

[image: USC]

[image: What's new]